# How to stop a ListView at a specific list item while it's flinging?

Tags: android, listview

I'm writing a time chooser widget  that consists of several ListViews(days, hours, minutes etc.). The minutes ListView has Integer.MAX_VALUE elements(repeating 0-59 over and over).
Whenever the user flings the list I want it to stop at 0, 15, 30 or 45. I tried to use setSelection but even though it selects the proper element it doesn't nullify the fling velocity so the list keeps on flinging.

Please help me if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help! I tried it and even though it stopped the listview, the position where it came to a halt was slightly different every time so in the end I used another solution.

```
if((firstVisibleItem % 60 == 13 || firstVisibleItem % 60 == 28 || firstVisibleItem % 60 == 43 || firstVisibleItem % 60 == 58) && !stopped)
{
    MotionEvent me = MotionEvent.obtain(10, SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),     MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 0, 0, 0); 
    MotionEvent me2 = MotionEvent.obtain(10, SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 0, 0, 0); 
    mMinutesListView.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
    mMinutesListView.dispatchTouchEvent(me2);
    mMinutesListView.setSelection(firstVisibleItem);
    stopped = true;
}
```

And then in the onScrollStateChanged method in case of a SCROLL_STATE_FLING I set the "stopped" boolean variable to false.

Answer (score 2):

[ListView: public void smoothScrollToPosition (int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29)

Maybe this will help you. Never used it but it looks like it could be a solution.